# ¿Como enviar una imagen del back end al front end con Node js & Express?

Tags: nodejs, express

tengo el siguiente problema, necesito enviar la respuesta de una petición a la vista y no sé como hacerlo ya que soy nuevo con Node. Lei por todos lados pero no encontré nada.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var rp = require('request-promise');

var options = {
  uri: 'http://tapas.clarin.com/tapa/1990/02/22/19900222_thumb.jpg',

  headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
  },
  json: true // Json parse
};

rp(options)
  .then( res => {
    console.log(res)
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
  });

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on localhost:3000');
});
```

Imprimiendo esta línea `console.log(res)` me sale la imagen en binario por consola, pero lo que necesito es enviar esa imagen a la vista para ser mostrada. ¿Alguna idea de como lograrlo ?

Mi vista es bien simple:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Tapas Clarin</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="tapas">
        <!-- Acá quiero mostrar la imagen -->
    </div>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira este [enlace]  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772394/how-to-upload-display-and-save-images-using-node-js-and-express)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el archivo app.js agrega:

```
app.get('/image', function(req, res, next) {
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'image/jpg'});
    fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/images/miImagen.jpg').pipe(res);
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después en el navegador http://localhost:4001/image (depende el puerto que tengas configurado)

Ahora bien, como necesitas una imagen de la web añade una libería llamada
[image-downloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-downloader)

Por lo tanto en app.js

```
const download = require('image-downloader')
const options = {
  url: 'http://tapas.clarin.com/tapa/1990/02/22/19900222_thumb.jpg',
  dest: __dirname + '/public/images/'
}
app.get('/imageFromWeb', function(req, res, next) {
    download.image(options)
    .then(({ filename, image }) => {
      console.log('File saved to', filename)
      res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'image/jpg'});
      fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/images/19900222_thumb.jpg').pipe(res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      res.json(500)
    })
});
```

Después en el navegador http://localhost:4001/imageFromWeb(depende el puerto que tengas configurado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso que no sea necesario usar NodeJS para mostrar la imagen, usa un [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) de html.

Comment: Gracias GENIO :D